# Laravel 4 form collections

Tags: forms, symfony, laravel, laravel-4

A few days ago I was discover  http://laravel.com/ the next generation framework for php5.3.

I want to switch from symfony2 to laravel4 but my question is how laravel solve embedding forms problem like symfony2 collection?

Is there a generic solution in laravel4 or I have to implement my own solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also new to [laravel-4](/questions/tagged/laravel-4), and I like it very much. If you are looking for **[Symfony2 collection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html)** type custom field, then I think in [laravel-4](/questions/tagged/laravel-4) **[Custom Macros](http://laravel.com/docs/html#custom-macros)** will do the work

> It's easy to define your own custom Form class helpers called "macros"

Answer (score -1):

Laravel 4 has the HTML builder built in. This also includes the Form builder.

See: http://laravel.com/docs/html

You are also able to write custom macros for each `HTML` and `FORM`.